# Returning different attributes in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write some code which will append the href of links after them when a button is clicked. So:

- Google
- Amazon
- Facebook

would turn to

- Google (www.google.com)
- Amazon (www.amazon.com)
- Facebook (www.facebook.com)

My code just puts (www.google.com) after every link, however. I suspect I'm meant to use `$.each()` in some way, but can't find an online example which doesn't just return a string.

My code is:

```
$(document).on('click', "#button", function(){
    $("a").each(function(){
        var www = $("a")
                    .attr("href")
                    .replace('http://',' &#40;');   
        $("a").after(www + '&#41;');
    });
});
```

How can I amend it to add the correct links? Thank you.

Comment: The second `$("a")` is *also* selecting all the `<a>` tags, hence you're operating on all of them, every time. Read the docs for `each`.

Comment: You are selecting all a elements again with $("a") for each element in the loop. @Yury's answer is correct, use the $(this) element to handle the elements your first selector found.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get attribute of the current element. Which is accessible through current function context.

```
var $this = $(this),
    www = $this.attr("href").replace('http://',' &#40;'); 
$this.after(www + '&#41;');
```

```js
$('#links').click(function(){
  $('a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    
    $this.after($this.attr('href'));
  });  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="links">Links</button>
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
<a href="http://foogle.com">foogle</a>
<a href="http://boogle.com">boogle</a>
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried that earlier. It just adds all three hrefs after each link for some reason!

Comment: Awesome - thanks very much, your expanded version does just the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the attribute of the current item when you iterate through the `each` fucntion:

```
$(document).on('click', "#button", function(){
  $("a").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var www = $this.attr("href").replace('http://',' &#40;');  
    $this.after(www + '&#41;');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads, you would have to save the default value to be used as the base text for each click of the link.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  //Save the initial text of the link
  $('ul li a').attr('data-default', function() {
    return $(this).text();
  });
  
  $('ul li a').on('click', function(e) {
    
    //prevent default action
    e.preventDefault()
    
    //append the value of href property to initial value and set as test of link
    $(this).text( function() {
      return $(this).data('default') + ' ( ' + this.href + ' ) ';
    });
  
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add the same class to the links

```
<a href='www.google.com' class='link' >google</a>
<a href='www.google2.com' class='link' >google2</a>
<a href='www.google3.com' class='link' >google3</a>
```

Second you will have to create on object with all the different links

```
$(document).on('click', "#button", function(){
    var links = $('.link');
    $.each(links, function(index,value){ 
        var www = value.attr("href").replace('http://',' &#40;');  
        $(this).after(www + '&#41;');
    });
});
```

This should work, as i use it all the time, the only thing that i have not tried is the .after()